# How to give a custom path for ivy:retrieve

Tags: ant, jenkins, ivy

I'm using Jenkins, Ivy and Ant for my builds.

I have the following lines:

```
<echo>${env.WORKSPACE}\${componentname}.Test.Unit\lib\</echo>
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${env.WORKSPACE}\${componentname}.Test.Unit\lib\[artifact].[ext]" transitive="false"/>
```

echo returns this:

```
[echo] C:\Jenkins\workspace\Productv1.0~Common.Utility\Common.Utility\lib\
```

But the retrieve call doesn't seem to place the libraries there.

Is this possible with the pattern parameter or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for my on Linux

```
<echo>${env.HOME}/tmp/Test.Unit/lib/</echo>
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${env.HOME}/tmp/Test.Unit/lib/[artifact].[ext]" transitive="false"/>
```

Files are placed where I expect them:

```
$ find /home/mark/tmp/Test.Unit/lib/
/home/mark/tmp/Test.Unit/lib/
/home/mark/tmp/Test.Unit/lib/commons-lang.jar
/home/mark/tmp/Test.Unit/lib/junit.jar
```